# Java Card: Problems selecting app with APDUtool

Tags: eclipse, javacard, apdu

*I'm using Eclipse with EclipseJCDE.*

I made a simple java card applet as a `.cap` file to install on the simulator. I don't know if the installation failed because the download script is a bunch of ADPU commands which I don't understand. Is there any way to see what applets are currently on the simulator and what their AIDs are?

I then made a script for ADPUtool with just one command, selecting the applet. According to the `.jca` file in my project.

- The AID for my applet:

  `0x1:0x2:0x3:0x4:0x5:0x6:0x7:0x8:0x9:0x0:0x0`.
- The command I made for selecting the applet:

  `0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x0b 0x1 0x2 0x3 0x4 0x5 0x6 0x7 0x8 0x9 0x0 0x0`

The `0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00` at the beginning is for the select command, then `0x0b` for the length, than the AID, and then `0x0` at the end for the Le byte which I don't think matters for this command. When I run this script with the ADPU tool I get this:

- **CLA:** 00
- **INS:** a4
- **P1:** 04
- **P2:** 00
- **Lc:** 0b 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
- **Le:** 00
- **SW1:** 6d
- **SW2:** 00

I believe the **SW1** and **SW2** bytes are the response to my command and I think 6d means it didn't find or wasn't able to load the applet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you explain me how you get this corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6D00 means bad instruction (INS byte 'A4' not existing in class '00').

Post full trace of APDUs after ATR else I recommend you to check section 10 from http://www.etsi.eu/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102221/08.02.00_60/ts_102221v080200p.pdf, for example.